# Exception calling "Create" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed

Tags: powershell

I was trying to run a powershell code which invokes a webrequest but i get an error as

```
"Exception calling "Create" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."
```

My code is below, when i run it it give me the above error, im executing the script in context of powershell v2.

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
$wname = "101.172.171.149"
$uuid = "f7c89b32-21a0-4a6f-80b2-b6d8bb33b1c7"
[string]$URI = "https://$wname/rest/wflows/$uuid/jobs"
$request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($uri)
$request.Credentials = $credential
$request.CookieContainer = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer

$request.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=utf-8"
$request.Method = "Post"
$request.keepAlive = $false
$requestStream = $request.GetRequestStream()
$streamWriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($requestStream)
$streamWriter.Write($body)
$streamWriter.flush()
$streamWriter.close()
$responseStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
$stream = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $responseStream
$xmlDump = $stream.ReadToEnd()
$output = [xml]$xmlDump
$response.close()
```

Comment: Your question doesn't show how $wname or $uuid are assigned nor what values you are trying to use.  Edit the question to show your test values that are failing.

Comment: Hello i have updated the values for both the variables

Comment: Where is the error appearing?

Comment: I guess the problem is that `$wname` and `$uuid` is not available when you are constructing $URI (scope issue?), so you get an URL like "https:///rest/wflows//jobs". Attempting to create a HttpWebRequest will fail exactly the way you described with an URL like that. You can verify by `Write-Host $URI` just prior creating the `$request` variable.

Comment: Using your code on a Win7 v2.0 powershell, I do not get an error at Create().  Later at GetRequestStream() there is a correct failure to connect.