# Ansible gives error on wait for module in ver 2.9 it gives missing bracket error

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Issue with using wait_for command in Ansible
I am using Ansible version 2.9.9 , when I am using

```yaml
    - name: wait for port 1433 to open
    
      wait_for:
    
             host: 10.20.30.20
    
             port: 1433
    
             state: started
    
             timeout: 30
    
             delay: 0
```

I am getting following error when I run the playbook

```bash
module_stderr: Exception calling Create with 1 arguments  at line.. def _ansiballz_main() An expression was expected after '('. Missing argument in parameter list if scriptdir is not Missing ( after if in if statement
```

Comment: can you confirm that is the code in use? there is a missing space , as it should be `- name`;  YAML requires that the syntax is followed, an indentation plays a major role in the interpretation of the commands

Comment: also note that the module expects [port](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html#parameter-port) to be an integer, in the example provided it is a string (also the name of the task does not match the value that is evaluated)

Comment: I have corrected it now. There is a space in the between the - and name. Thank you for pointing it out. I have tried using the port and IP address without quotes and get the same error.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error (with ansible-core 2.13.8), have you tried using the module with FQDN (`ansible.builtin.wait_for:` instead of `wait_for:`)?

Comment: I dont think I can use builtin for version 2.9.  I have tried anyway ansible.builtin.wait_for: host=10.10.10.10 port=1433 timeout=1    I get the same error.

Comment: A [post with a similar error as yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152313/exception-calling-create-with-1-arguments-invalid-uri-the-hostname-coul) sure does seem like the shell is PowerShell and not python; you'll have to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75646823/edit) and include more details than just the **one task**